# Regex ignore word and fixing dble slash

Tags: python, regex

Trying to get a regex, I need it to ignore a specific word but my regex not working correctly.

Ex. Our ignore word will be "timeline" and fixing the last 3 lines.

Actually, my regex get timeline but i don't need this.
example :

```
https://www.example.com/test/timeline (actually)
https://www.example.com/test (Perfect)
```

I have a little bug, i don't know why double slash is not included correctly on the 3 last lines?

here's my regex : https://regex101.com/r/gPJZeZ/1

How can I ignore timeline and fixing the double slash?

Comment: Which Regex Parser are you using?

Comment: @OmegaMan, thanks for your reply i'm using python.

Comment: Then put that in the tag line in future questions. The more information you can give the better.

Comment: I am looking at your regex demo and it's unclear what are you trying to match. There are char like `% ?` that you want to skip...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude timeline.

`(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com/(?!(?:.+/)?[\w.-]*?timeline)(?:.+/)?([\w.-]+)|%[^?/\r\n]*`

https://regex101.com/r/AkeDkC/1

The assertion will match *timeline* if it is there, and of course fail then.

You can add special stuff before/after  *timeline* as necessary.

Some other fixups are included as well.

Formatted

```
    (?: https?:// )?
    (?: www\. )?
    facebook\.com/
    (?!
         (?: .+ / )?
         [\w.-]*?
         timeline
    )
    (?: .+ / )?
    ( [\w.-]+ )                   # (1)
 |  
    % [^?/\r\n]*
```

***Update***

Up to the word `timeline` but no further ..

`(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com/(?:.+/)?((?:(?!timeline)[\w.-])+)|%[^?/\r\n]*`

https://regex101.com/r/7pu13K/1

```
    (?: https?:// )?
    (?: www\. )?
    facebook\.com/
    (?: .+ / )?
    (                             # (1 start)
         (?:
              (?! timeline )
              [\w.-] 
         )+
    )                             # (1 end)
 |  
    % [^?/\r\n]*
```

Comment: @sln, i need just to remove the Word "timeline" not exclude url completly.i accept your solution if the word timeline is ignored. thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @Spirlo - Ok added it.